# How many US states legislatures would currently support an amendment restricting the ownership of guns?

Tags: united-states, guns

In order to seriously change the existing gun laws in the US, an amendment would be required for the US Constitution that would partially or fully override the 2nd amendment. But in order to pass such an amendment, legislatures of 3/4s of all US states must agree to it. Is there currently a list of states that would support such an amendment? I presume New York would and Texas wouldn't, but it would be interesting to see a wider list.

Comment: I can answer based on the assumption that voting would go down party lines. Is the notion that "republican controlled legistatures would not vote for a change to the second amendment" a reasonable assumption?

Comment: @JamesK are Democrats uniformly in favor of restricting the 2nd amendment?

Comment: I don't think so, but considering the partisan split would at least provide a lower bound.

Comment: Don't even be too sure about New York.  New York City might, but the rest of the state is likely to have different attitudes.

Comment: To echo @jamesqf, New York is a large state with dozens of representatives from rural parts of the state where gun ownership is popular and even practical. There are more Republican senators than Democrat. It's hardly a foregone conclusion. Furthermore, your question's premise is flawed: if you consider the constitutional restrictions that exist in New York City and others, and consider that they could be extended to the rest of the country without amending the constitution, it's clear that it would be possible to effect a serious change to US gun laws without amending the constitution.

Comment: VTC as too broad. While you may be able to find polls (even with enough effort, state level polls), the question as asked is rather vague and broad. Specific proposals poll far better than generic "restrict" (source: 538), while other specific proposal poll really poorly. Is your question specifically about state level support to specifically "repeal 2d Amendment"? Or some other proposal?

Comment: @user4012 I'm interested in the level of support towards changing the 2nd amendment through the Constitution. That's narrow enough in my opinion.

Comment: @phoog weren't large sections of the NYC law struck down in court?

Comment: @JonathanReez - changing **in what way** is the critical missing detail. The answer would drastically depend on the clarification, based on existing polling data

Comment: @user4012 changing in some way towards the restriction of guns. Any way - from a full ban to the mildest adjustment.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know what NYC laws have been struck down in court, but I do know that I cannot buy any sort of gun in the city without a permit issued by the police department, or possess any sort of gun without a permit except in very limited circumstances, and I assume that this restriction has withstood second amendment challenges because it has been on the books for decades.  The fact that a similar restriction does not exist in any particular other place in the US is a function of that place's political process, not the US constitution.

Comment: This is exactly why we have a “hypothetical situation” close reason.  Just because Democrats *in general* favor gun control, doesn’t mean that a Democratic-controlled legislature would vote for an amendment. Public pressure, or the specific wording, or any number of other things can affect what actually happens. Sorry - it’s an interesting question, just not a good fit.

Comment: @phoog: Unfortunately, some jurisdictions like NYC choose to ignore the Constitution when it suits them.  Just as it has often historically suited various jurisdictions to ignore the 1st Amendment's establishment of religion clause or the 14th Amendment's guarantee of equal rights, or the way the DEA & other law enforcement agencies ignore the bits about search & seizure, and taking of private property...

Comment: @jamesqf I really find it difficult to believe that New York city's gun laws haven't been challenged on constitutional grounds and upheld.  If that is true, then I don't see how you can say that the city and state have ignored the constitution.

Comment: @phoog:  SCOTUS doesn't elect to hear a lot of constitutional challenges to gun regulations as a rule, so they revert back to the lower court jurisdictions.  Some states, such as Maryland, are may issue, but upon initial appeal, will reverse and allow the purchaser to buy the gun and avoid the case climbing hire to avoid a constitutional challenge.

Comment: @phoog: The courts have sometimes been quite willing to go along with laws that are obvious violations of the Constitution.  For one example (of many), nearly a century of upholding racial discrimination laws.